# How to update a database/table using C# & show the changes instant in GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview, datagrid

I'm trying to update a tale with `C#`, but, I'm not able to to that. I want to show all the data in GridView including the updated rows as well. Any help much appreciated.

```
String connectionString = @"Data Source=11.71.38.9;Database=DB;User Id=admin;Password=12345";
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("Update StudentsData set Name = ('" + txtBoxName.Text.ToString() + "', Address = '" + txtBoxAddress.Text.ToString() + "', Centre = '" + txtBoxCenter.Text.ToString() + "', City = '" + txtBoxCity.Text.ToString() + "', State = '" + txtBoxState.Text.ToString() + "' where ID = '" + txtBoxID.Text.ToString() + "')", sqlCon);
    sqlData.Fill(dtbl);
    CRUDDB.DataSource = dtbl;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Incorrect syntax near ','. Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   StackTrace: at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject

Comment: What exact issue you are facing with this? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes bro, I'm getting this error:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Incorrect syntax near ','.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject

Comment: You don't need `(` in `set Name = ('` also you don't need `)` in `"')"`. You might want to read more about UPDATE sql query and it's syntax.

Comment: Please add any additional information into your question, not in a comment. I did it for you this time

Comment: You need to read more about 2 things. 1) `sql`  and the `UPDATE` statement. 2) C# and parametrized queries. The last one is more important than you think, the code you have now is wide open for sql injection hacking

Comment: @GuidoG Thanks bro for your help & for correcting my question. I fixed when I realized I'm using the wrong SQL update query. Buddy Server, DB, ID, Password everything is wrong, do not need to worry about that.